# usage of "join" and "notification.channels" fields in phabricator bot json config file

Tags: php, xmpp, phabricator

I am trying to build a phabricator bot that sends messages to jabber chat members whenever there are new stories in phabricator. I know what the other fields in the bot configuration json file mean. I want to know what the "join" and  "notification.channels" field signify. I looked at the documentation but these two fields have not been explained. The default value in the example_config.json are

```
"join" : [ "#phabot-test" ],
"notification.channels" : ["#phabot-test"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These settings relate to [IRC - Internet Relay Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat). IRC is a chat system that's been around for years. As well as private messaging between users, it also supports chat rooms. On IRC, chat rooms are called *channels*; you can *join* and *part* a channel to enter or leave it. Channel names start with a `#` sign.

The `join` setting is a list of channels to join when the bot starts. The `notification.channels` is a list of channels where the bot should announce events. Often this will be the same list, as in your example, but you might want the bot to sit quietly in a channel & be available to answer questions.

There's some more documentation about setting up a Phabricator chat bot [in the Phabricator docs](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabdev/article/chatbot/).

Comment: Its specific to IRC, that’s true. But the difference between and acceptable values in both: `notification.channels` and `join` are still confusing.  I stumbled on that same question when I configured `{join:["#a","#b"], "notification.channels": ["#a"]}`  and I get notification in all channels in `join`. Even though I specified only one in `notification.channels`. Maybe that the question was about that.